# transmit a value to return by reference in C++

Tags: c++

I have a function that receives two references of integer. A boolean indicator  allows to choose  one time the first reference and one time the second reference as it is illustrated in the code below :

1) I don't understand the meaning of alterne(n,p) = 0 and alterne(n,p) = 12

2) and the function of the static bool indic;

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int & alterne (int &, int &);

int main()
{
    int n=1, p=3, q=5;

    alterne(n,p) = 0;
    cout << "n=" << n << "p=" << p << "\n" ;

    alterne(p,q) = 12;
    cout << "p=" << p << "q=" << q << "\n" ;
}

int & alterne (int & n1, int & n2)
{
    static bool indic = true;
    if (indic) { indic =false; return n1; }
    else       { indic = true; return n2 ; }
}
```

thank you for your consideration

Comment: `alterne` is a switch.

Comment: yes. but my concern is why the program returns  n=0  p=3 rather than (n=1 and p=3)  and  p= 3 q= 12 rather than (p=3 and q=5) ?

Comment: l don't understand the meaning of alterne(n,p) = 0;

Comment: and the role of if (indic) {indic =false; return n1;}

Comment: Do you know how static variables inside functions work? That might explain your confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Does the following make sense to you? It's a function which takes an `int` by reference and assigns a new value to it.

```
void foo(int& x)
{
    x = 33;
}
```

> 1) I don't understand the meaning of `alterne(n,p) = 0` and `alterne(n,p) = 12`

For your question, `alterne` returns `int&`. So you basically have the same situation as above (i.e., a reference to an `int` is available and ultimately a new value is assigned to the referenced `int`).

```
alterne(n, p) = 0;
// first call is equivalent to getting an `int&` to `n`
// then performing n = 0;

alterne(p, q) = 12;
// second call is equivalent to getting an `int&` to `q`
// then performing q = 12;
```

> 2) and the function of the `static bool indic;`

This is a variable local to the `alterne` function but has a lifetime such that the same `bool` is available in all calls to the function. It is initialized once and read during each function call. Therefore, it's initialized to `true` once which is available on the 1st function call and is toggled between `false` and `true` on each subsequent function call.

Answer (score 1):

```
int & alterne (int & n1, int & n2)
{
    static bool indic = true;
    if (indic) { indic =false; return n1; }
    else       { indic = true; return n2 ; }
}
```

Lets break down the function:

```
static bool indic = true;
```

First there is a static variable inside a function body. Static here means that the life time of the variable is global, meaning it retains its value between function calls. The firs time you call `alterne()` it is `ture`.

```
    if (indic) { indic =false; return n1; }
    else       { indic = true; return n2 ; }
```

This basically toggles the variable `indic`. If it is ture it is false after. And since indic retains its value between function calls, the function `alterne()` basically alternates between returning `n1` and `n2` - starting with `n1`.

```
int & alterne (int & n1, int & n2)
```

The function takes 2 references to ints and returns a reference to `int`. And as we saw above it actually once returns the reference to `n1` and then `n2` and so on.

```
 alterne(n,p) = 0
```

`alterne(n,p)` returns either n or p (based on the current value of `indic` variable and then assigns 0 to it. Since this is the first call to alterne it is the same as doing `n = 0;`

```
alterne(p,q) = 12;
```

Since this is the second call to `alterne()` it is the same as `q = 12;`

Hope this helps you in anyway.

Answer (score 0):

alterne function is a switch that at first call return first argument by reference then in second time return second argument by reference .

Compiler after calling alterne function will replace left side of assign operator with return reference . then right side of assign operator will copy into it.